# Manipulating contend of a vsdx-file automatically

Tags: xml, vba, visual-studio, zip, visio

I am using Visio 2013 Standard. Futher I have got Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition.

**This is what I try to do at the end:**

Changing e.g. name of a connector between two shapes, giving it a name from outside of Visio (e.g. a txt- or csv-file) automatically.  Although, I require some basic underständing.

**Background:**

I write this (preferably) as a user of Visio. I am working as a embedded software developer. Usually I have got nothing to do with XML or VB-packages.

I want to make project-data more easier to understand. Values and names are documented in doors. But Visio shows so far just names. I want to see those values kept in Doors on Visio-diagramms.

It is easy to get a txt- or csv-file from Doors. But so far I did not find a easy way to get this data into Visio.

**The reason why I am thinking about XML and packages:**

What we have got at work is Visio 2013 Standard (not Professional). So far as I understand Visio 2013 Professional is providing this solution (See first sentence of description.), only.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-to-shapes-in-your-drawing-d174b3fd-3079-42fd-81e8-2dbf8d38bb03

**This I have read - or tried to understand:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj649391.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/jj228622.aspx

**Therefore, this is my first step I tried:**

1) I draw two shapes with Visio, connecting them with a connector. The connector has got a name which I surely will find in any XML-file later. I saved the file and closed it.

2) Changed the type of the file from .vsdx to .zip

3) Unzipped the folder

4) Searched for the name of the connector and found it in folder 'page1'

5) Changed the name of the connection via Notepad++

6) Unzipped the folders again

7) Changed the type from .zip to .vsdx

8) Tried to open the regained .vsdx-file but failed. Visio says that it can't open the file or component, because it is corrupted.

**This is what I suppose:**

The problem lies in the fact that xml-files are not the same as vsdx-files:

- I suppose as vsdx-files has to be handled as one package (and not as xml-file) I have to (!) use Visual Studio instead of a simple change via Notepad++.
- I suppose that if using Visual Studio I will have the advantage to find and handle those objects. which I want manipulate, more dynamically - as paths and folderstructure of the Viso-project may not always be the same.
- I suppose there is no solution from within Visio, exept I will have got the Professional-Version instead.

**These are my questions:**

- What is the reason why opening the regained vsdx-file failed?
- Is it true what I suppose?

a) Do I have to use Visual Studio?

b) What will be the disadvantage if not using Visual Studio?

c) Without a Visio 2013 Professional version, will there be no possibility for automatically changing connector names from within Visio?

d) If having Visio 2013 Professional do have to use macros, which could mean that I need to know about OPC, XML and packages, too?

e) Using Visio 2013 itself to solve my task, does this really require a Visio 2013 Professional version?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your link says following : As mentioned, past versions of Visio also included an XML-based file format, the Visio XML Drawing Format or .vdx. (In previous versions of Visio, the schema used for the Visio XML Drawing Format is called DatadiagramML.) Some pieces from the Visio XML schema have stayed the same between the two file formats. For example, the Windows element and its children remain unchanged─with the exception that the Windows element is now a root element of an XML document (window.xml).

Comment: To write XML you can use lots of programming languages.  The vsdx is the schema for Visio that checks the the xml data meets the Visio requirements.  There are plenty of on-line xml checkers that you can use to validate your xml is correct against the schema.  You can validate xml files in VS using menu : Project : Add New : Xml file.    Then past your xml into the view.  Errors will show up in the Error list like any compiler error.

Comment: Use the *SDK*, not raw XML. And upgrade to a fresh version of Visual Studio. The community editions are free and provide the same features as Pro. Visual Studio *already* contains

Comment: BTW post your *actual* code. Did you try the code in the first link? You *don't* need to unzip anything, that's what the Package class is for. You shouldn't perform any of the steps you describe here. You didn't describe any *relevant* steps though

Comment: @jdweng `vsdx` *is* a zipped package of XML files. There's no reason to deal with XML directly though, that's the job of the SDK. No need to unzip, no need to read individual XML files. In fact, the first link shows how to do it.

Comment: @Tinitus Visio allows binding some attributes to data. You may not need any code to do what you ask. Are the shapes fixed or generated programmatically? Could you create a Visio file perhaps that binds to data when opened by a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than manipulate raw content, I would create a VBA-enabled Visio file that contains a routine to search a Visio file for the connector, change the name and then re-save the file. You can amend this routine to search for multiple files or multiple shapes, and you can also search on the shape master to adjust connectors that have any name.

You could also use Visio interop tools in Visual Studio to create an application that does the same thing as I have described in my VBA approach above.

The advantage of doing this is that you avoid digging into the raw data with the real potential of corrupting the files - as you have found. It will also make accidental changes less likely (e.g. the name value you are looking for may occur in multiple places in the XML in different contexts and you may just change the wrong one).

With the above explanation out of the way, here are the answers to your questions:

1. You don't have to use Visual Studio
2. No disadvantage not using Visual Studio if you have another way
   that works (e.g. VBA). A master Visio file would be more portable,
   especially in a corporate context where the IT is locked down for
   new applications.
3. As shown above, the changes you want can be done even if you
   don't have Visual Studio (e.g. through VBA)
4. By using the Visio interop assemblies or Visio itself, you do not
   need to know XML etc.
5. This will be possible with any edition of Visio, not just the Professional version.

Using the tools that come with the program makes the changes you want easier and safer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and a direction!  Above I added a question as you are mentining Visio interop tools.

Comment: There's no reason to use VBA when `vsdx` and all other Office formats were written to allow generation and consumption *without* requiring a Visio installation. You *can't* use interop on a web server for example, both because you *can't* buy a license for every end user and because you *can't* afford to start a separate Visio or Excel instance for every request. The SDK doesn't require raw content manipulation either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the question at hand - the OP has both Visio and Visual Studio (don't know what edition of VS). While your comment is valid generally, in this case unnecessary.

Comment: @AJD yes, Visual Studio. Which means VBA isn't available. It's also not necessary or recommended. Not only because it doesn't work on servers, it also requires elevation of priviledges. There's a reason Microsoft introduced Visio Services 8 years ago, and a reason VBA didn't work there either.

Comment: @AJD while this answer is applicable in *some* cases, this isn't what the question is about. In fact, with Visio you wouldn't even need VBA to bind shape attributes to data. Check [Add data sets to shapes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-data-sets-to-shapes-05264f86-4948-4132-8b4a-91636e6c9a7e)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Read my comment again and the OP, OP also has Visio - VBA is available. The OP does not say anything about data binding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I have got Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition. To be more exactly: Version 9.0, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1